# iptables DROP on port only for remote connections

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, iptables

I have several docker containers running on my virtual machine.

One of them exposes `8000` port with an HTTP server (django/python). On the other hand, nginx is installed, it listens `80` port and proxy pass to 8000:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

It works perfectly. But if I connect to 8000 port directly from browser, like:

```
http://example.com:8000/
```

it returns me the response from internal docker handler.

How to close that 8000 port and not to hurt everything?

I tried to do this with `iptables` utility but seems like docker created a lot of own rules, and I do not whether I will create a normal one without hurting these docker's rules :

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Planned to do:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j REJECT
```

Is it OK?

Comment: Known _issue_. https://medium.com/@ebuschini/iptables-and-docker-95e2496f0b45. I did not write this nor do I use it but gives you a good insight into the problem.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only ports you explicitly publish with the `docker run -p` option (or the Docker Compose `ports:` option) are reachable from other hosts.  You don't need this option just to communicate between containers; two containers that are on the same Docker-internal network can communicate using each others' container names as hostnames, and the container-internal port, without any "publish" or "expose" option.

In short, remove the `-p` option from your backend container, and it won't be directly reachable from off-host.  You don't need to manually change `iptables` rules.